# fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\storage\fonts/

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to generate pdf file in laravel but I am getting the error ErrorException (E_WARNING)
fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\storage\fonts/\2af8d92bcac2cf6390f0434ec5aa8fe6.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
Please help. My controller code these two lines of code,

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/personalpdf', compact('user','result'));
                return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf/personalpdf');
```

other code work will and I can display data,  but pdf file can not be generated.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use PDF;
use Auth;

class PdfController extends Controller
{
public function personalpdf()
    {
        if(\Auth::check()){
            $user = \Auth::user();
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $result = DB::table('education')->where('education.degree' ,'=','PHD')->where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->get();
           // return view('pdf/personalpdf',compact('user', 'result'));
            $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/personalpdf', compact('user','result'));
            return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf/personalpdf');

        }else {
            return view('pdf/personalpdf');
        }
    }
}
```

I installed dompdf, and all other code is ok, I did it from totural. but now getting the given error fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\storage\fonts/\2af8d92bcac2cf6390f0434ec5aa8fe6.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
The routes code is here.

```
Route::get('pdf/personalpdf','PdfController@personalpdf');
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check the pdf path.

Comment: pdf path is ok,

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: It seems to be requesting a *font* from your *storage* directory, which is unusual. Does that font exist in that directory?

Comment: it seems like you need to create a fonts folder in the storage folder  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/269

Answer (score 11):

Yeah, I encountered this same challenge today and creating an empty folder titled "fonts" in the storage folder, did the trick for me.

Comment: Yes. Creating an empty folder at that path.. worked for me. Thanks.!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default font like

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/personalpdf', compact('user','result'))->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use various methods to fix this issue.

**Use the default font**

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf/personalpdf', compact('user','result'))->setOptions(['defaultFont' => 'sans-serif']);
```

**Create folder**

```
mkdir /home/mykarnik/public_html/storage/fonts/
```

**if the above one doesn't work make related file**

```
mkdir /home/mykarnik/public_html/storage/fonts/{font-file-name.ufm}
```

if you are using Linux please give permissions (not related to the question but for those who view this and developing with Linux)

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/mykarnik/public_html/storage/fonts/
```

Answer (score 0):

fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\prolearning\storage\fonts/\2af8d92bcac2cf6390f0434ec5aa8fe6.ufm): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

or directory.

STEPS

1. crate "fonts" Folder inside storage
2. create file "2af8d92bcac2cf6390f0434ec5aa8fe6.ufm" or other "File Name" Which show in error inside "fonts" Folder
3. Giving Permission "fonts" Folder

Answer (score 0):

What used to cause this error is as a result of using fontawesome in form of cdn or any other cdn. All what you need to do is to download the fontawesome or any other forms of cdn that might be resulting to that related error to your project and make a path to public\fonts\all.css.

Note: the above path is in my own case.

I believe your using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf package in Laravel and below neccessary steps has been done.

**Steps:**

a) Install barryvdh/laravel-dompdf:

`composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`

b) Add below code to `config/app.php` file:

`'providers' => [Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class, ],`

`'aliases' => ['PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class, ],`

c) Generate dompdf.php file to link public/fonts/your-css.css: config/dompdf.php

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider" --tag=config`

d) Generate PDF result:

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('view_receipt', ['sale' => $sale, 'payment' => $payment]);`

`return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');`

*I hope this is helpful to someone.*